# Can i use wrt54gv7 firmware on my WRT54Gv8

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dd-wrt

I have a router with model WRT54Gv8

Edited : Router Model Linksys WRT54Gv8 / GSv7 / G2v1

firmware version as Firmware: DD-WRT v24-sp2 (10/30/08) micro - build 10709M NEWD Eko

But when i go to http://dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database
I see WRT54Gv8 listed  in router-database

but can't find WRT54Gv8 under other-downloads\beta

but i do see WRT54Gv7

Can i use firmware build for WRT54Gv7 on my WRT54Gv8

Comment: What build are you currently on build number wise.

Comment: DD-WRT v24-sp2 (10/30/08) micro - build 10709M NEWD Eko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use the V7 firmware on your device.

Looking [here](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/How_To_Flash_the_WRT54Gv8), your router uses the `Generic` builds, using the `Micro Generic` predominantly.

As such, you'll find your routers firmware in the `Broadcom` folder, the `Micro Generic` version, eg, [here](ftp://ftp.dd-wrt.com/betas/2016/02-17-2016-r29114/broadcom/). The reason you have found a separate firmware for the `WRT54Gv7` is that it used an Atheros CPU instead of a Broadcom one, and requires it's own special build to work. Using the wrong firmware may be difficult, if possible, to recover from, so definitely don't flash that one.

Comment: can i use dd-wrt.v24_mini_wrt54g.bin from ftp://ftp.dd-wrt.com/betas/2016/02-17-2016-r29114/broadcom/?

Comment: @SeanClt The wiki for your model uses `dd-wrt.v24_micro_generic.bin`, as such, I'd stick with that one.

Comment: I just edited the question and added Edited : Router Model Linksys WRT54Gv8 / GSv7 / G2v1  i saw this listed on status page

Comment: testing will share the results

Comment: wow nice upgrade successful Firmware: DD-WRT v3.0-r29114 micro (02/17/16)
Time: 01:01:18 up 1 min, load average: 0.18, 0.05, 0.01

Comment: I have to say this superuser.com rock